# How to pass a pandas dataframe to `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` or `scipy.stats.linregress`

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

Similar question here: [Pass Pandas DataFrame to Scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35233664/pass-pandas-dataframe-to-scipy-optimize-curve-fit)

I now have a dataframe with shape=(100, 4), i.e. four dependent vars Y1 to Y4. With another independent array m = [1, 2, 3, 4]. I need to make a linear model out of Ys and m, generating a predicted Y value.

How can I do it for the whole dataframe, without doing it in a for loop with each row of the dataframe?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.stats import linregress

Y = np.random.randn(100, 4) 
m = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])    

df = pd.DataFrame(Y, columns=['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4'])
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(m, row.values)
    print(slope, intercept)
```

Comment: "but it doesn't quite work for me" What exactly? Could you elaborate (unexpected outcome, errors, ...)?!

Comment: `.values` is the usual way of getting a numpy array from a dataframe.

Comment: @Cleb Hi, I've changed the code to show what I've tried, using for loop for each row.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's good practice to format the data with the observations on the rows. That is that each observation is described by the dimensions in the other columns, the variables (x1-4). Afterwards you can pass your explanatory variables to the model function along with the response (y), which can be one column of your data frame or outside but with the same number of rows.

Apparently the linregress function only fits a single explanatory variable onto a response variable.

For >2-dimensional modelling, I would suggest using other packages such as statsmodels or sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression

Below I go on with the former suggestion:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols

data = np.random.randn(100, 4)
y = np.random.randn(100)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'])

x1 = df['x1']
x2 = df['x2']
x3 = df['x3']
x4 = df['x4']

model = ols("y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4", df).fit()
print(model.summary())
```